# Get model in pydantic type validator

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

How can I, in a pydantic *type* validator, get the actual model? The idea is to read metadata from the `Field()` parameter.

This is what I end up with. I tried a `WrapValidator` as well, but it does not help, and the model does not appear in the context.

```py
from typing import Annotated, Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator, Field, ValidationInfo


def use_default_if_none[T](f: T | None, info: ValidationInfo) -> T | Any:
    if f is None:
        return 42 # QUESTION how to get the model here?
    else:
        return f


type IntDefault = Annotated[int, BeforeValidator(use_default_if_none)]


class Data(BaseModel):
    a: IntDefault = Field(default=42)


print(Data(a=None))
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible using annotated validators. They are explicitly independent of the model class they are used in. They cannot know, in which model they are used, if that makes sense.

To make this work you need validators, that are attached to the model class. One possible solution is to use a `field_validator`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class Data(BaseModel):
    a: IntDefault = Field(default=42)

    @field_validator("a", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value):
        if value is None:
            field = cls.model_fields["a"]
            return field.default

        return value

print(Data(a=None))
```

Which prints:

```
a=42
```

If you really want to achieve something along the lines of what you proposed, you need a far more advanced pattern using parametric types (by implementing `__class_item__`) to tell `IntDefault`, which model it is part of. See for example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator, Field


class IntDefault:
    def __class_getitem__(cls, item):
        def use_default_if_none(value, info):
            if value is None:
                return  item.model_fields[info.field_name].default

            return value
        
        return Annotated[int, BeforeValidator(use_default_if_none)]


class Data(BaseModel):
    a: IntDefault[Data] = Field(default=42)


print(Data(a=None))
```

But if possible I would really try to avoid it. I think the pattern based on the parametric type is too advanced and the simpler repetitive pattern I proposed above might be the better choice.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is a very interesting approach. Unfortunately, when `a` is defined, `Data` is not, so it's not possible to give it as type parameter. It does give me ideas to go forward, though. Thanks!

Comment: I missed the `from __future__ import annotations` import, which resolves the `NameError`. Otherwise I think one would need a bit more context to come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: I had forgotten about `__future__` Thanks, in the context of this question, you helped a lot already :)